# Не получается создать шаблонную функцию внутри шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, gcc, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь создать пустой шаблон внутри шаблонного класса, на что мне gcc отвечает:

> explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class
>   BaseStringBuilder’ template<>

```
#include <list>

template<class T>
class BaseStringBuilder
{
public:
    BaseStringBuilder() = default;

    template<>
    BaseStringBuilder(T &&str)
    {
        data.push_back(std::forward(str));
    }

    ~BaseStringBuilder() = default;

    template<>
    BaseStringBuilder& add(T &&str)
    {
        data.push_back(std::forward(str));
        return *this;
    }

    T build() const
    {
        T rtrn;

        for(auto i : data)
        {
            rtrn += i;
        }

        return rtrn;
    }

private:
    std::list<T> data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже все, что вам нужно, это следующее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class BaseStringBuilder
{
public:
    BaseStringBuilder() = default;

    template <typename U>      
    BaseStringBuilder( U &&str)
    {
        data.push_back(std::forward<T>(static_cast<T &&>( str )));
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    ~BaseStringBuilder() = default;

    template <typename U>      
    BaseStringBuilder & add(U &&str)
    {
        data.push_back(std::forward<T>(static_cast<T &&>( str )));
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
        return *this;
    }

    T build() const
    {
        T rtrn {};
            ^^^^^^^^^^

        for (auto i : data)
        {
            rtrn += i;
        }

        return rtrn;
    }

private:
    std::list<T> data;
};

int main()
{
    BaseStringBuilder<int> b(10);
    b.add(20);

    std::cout << b.build() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @ixSci А вы пробовали запустить?

Comment: Исправленный вариант работает, но staic_cast здесь лишний, тк с ним не будет работать преобразование char* -> QString

Comment: @Wanket У меня сегодня интернет не работает. По 10 минут загружается. Это важнее.:)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам тут шаблон?
Ведь в список произвольные данные "левого" типа не внести - так зачем тут объявлять что-то как шаблон?

А если вам зачем-то нужен шаблонный метод в классе - так нет вопросов,

```
template<typename U>
void superMethod(const U& uu);
```

Ну, или типа того...

Comment: Что бы работала универсальная ссылка. А реализацию этого шаблона как писать?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вам лучше сделать две перегрузки - для `T&` и для `T&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что Вам нужно, то вот:

```
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value>>
BaseStringBuilder(U &&str)
{
    data.push_back(std::forward<U>(str));
}
```

Получается *forwarding reference* + только для того же типа будет работать.

---

Ещё можно попробовать такой вариант, если нужно допустить типы, который могут быть конвертированы в `T`:

```
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
BaseStringBuilder(U &&str)
{
    data.emplace_back(std::forward<U>(str));
}
```

Comment: Намудрено то) Но к сожалению так не работает неявное преобразование в T(В моем случае char* в QString), так что пришлось std::forward убрать, да и данном случае думаю можно обойтись и без него

Comment: @Wanket, попробуйте второй вариант.

Comment: все равно не хочет.no matching function for call to 'forward'
        data.emplace_back(std::forward(str));         in instantiation of function template specialization 'BaseStringBuilder<QString>::BaseStringBuilder<char const (&)[11], std::enable_if<true, void> >'

Comment: Что-то мне припоминается, что в `forward` надо обязательно тип указывать... типа `forward<U>`.

Comment: @Harry, отличное замечание! Совсем из головы вылетело.

Comment: @Wanket, попробуйте обновлённый вариант. Кстати, Вы в курсе, что в Qt есть уже всё для эффективного слияния строк, через оператор %? Или Вы для себя это класс решили сделать?

Comment: Максимум +=, никакого % у QString не вижу

Comment: @Wanket, потому что он у `QStringBuilder`, который является внутренним классом. Читайте документацию по `QString`. Для `QString` можно применять `operator%`